# Embedding in PyTorch creates embedding with norm larger than max_norm

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose we have an embedding matrix of 10 vectors with dimension of 100, and we impose `max_norm=1`:

```
x = Embedding(num_embeddings=10, embedding_dim=100, max_norm=1)
```

In principle, every embedding should have norm less or equal to 1. However, when I print the vector norms, I get values much greater than 1:

```
for w in x.weight: 
    print(torch.norm(w))

> tensor(11.1873, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
> tensor(10.5264, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
> tensor(9.6809, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
> tensor(9.7507, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
> tensor(10.7940, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
> tensor(11.4134, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
> tensor(9.7021, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
> tensor(10.4027, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
> tensor(10.1210, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
> tensor(10.4552, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
```

Any particular reason why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: `max_norm` bounds the norm of the embedding, here you are calculating the norm of the weights, which is not bound to be 1. If you try to embed an input, and calculate the norm of the resulting embedding, that norm will be 1

Comment: How can I get the norm of the embedding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `max_norm` argument bounds the norm of the embedding, but not the norm of the weights.

To better understand this, you can run the following example:

```
from torch import LongTensor, norm
from torch.nn import Embedding

sentences = LongTensor([[1,2,4,5],[4,3,2,9]])
embedding = Embedding(num_embeddings=10, embedding_dim=100, max_norm=1)
for sentence in embedding(sentences):
    for word in sentence:
        print(norm(word))
```

This works by dividing each weight in the embedding vector by the norm of the embedding vector itself, and multiplying it by `max_norm`. In your example `max_norm=1`, hence it's equivalent to dividing by the norm.

To answer the question you asked in the comment, you can obtain the embedding of a sentence (vector containing word indexes taken from your dictionary), with `embedding(sentences)`, the norm using the 2 `for` loops above.